# How do I pass data from an array query to a view file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

## Hi there!

Since my last question was poorly described and not really a question, I've decided to re-brand my question.

### What is my question?

What is the best way to pass an array from my Firestore Database to my view file from my model file? Is my approach even correct?

### My current approach

Essentially three files are used to create the output. The code I used was from another function that does work, though it is a different query.

1. **Friends_Requests.swift** (View file)

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

struct Friends_Requests: View {
    @State var goBack: Bool = false
    @ObservedObject var friends_model = Friends_Model()

    
    var body: some View {
        if !goBack {
            VStack {
                
                Group{
                    Text("Your Friend Requests")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    Divider()
                }
                
                Spacer()
                List (friends_model.friend_requests) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
                .refreshable{
                    friends_model.getFriendRequestData()
                    
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                
                
                Spacer()
                
                Group {
                    HStack{
                        Text("Friends requests will appear here")
                    }
                }
                
                
                Group {
                    Divider()
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.goBack.toggle()
                            }
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.left.circle.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        }
                        .padding(.leading, 20)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if goBack {
            FriendsPanel()
        }
    }

struct Friends_Requests_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Friends_Requests()
    }
}
}
```

2. **Friends_Model.swift** (View model)

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import SwiftUI


class Friends_Model: ObservableObject {
 
    @Published var friend_requests = [Friends_Requests_Data]()

    
    
    func getFriendRequestData() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let email = user?.email ?? "error: email"
        
        let queryRef = db.collection("users").document(email)
        
        queryRef.getDocument { snapshot, error in
            
            //check for errors
            if error == nil {
                print("no errors")
                
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    
                                
                    self.friend_requests = snapshot.get("friendRequests") { d in
                        
                            //Create friend item for each document
                            return Friends_Requests_Data(id: d.documentID,
                                                email: d["friendRequests"] as? String ?? "")
                    }
                                
            } else {
                // handle error
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

3. **Friends_Requests_Data.swift** (Data model)

```
import Foundation

struct Friends_Requests_Data: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var email: String
}
```

### What error's am I getting?

- **Friends_Requests.swift** (View file)
  [image: Error in view file]
- **Friends_Model.swift** (View model)
  [image: Error in view model]

Comment: As to your error here: `List (friends_model.friend_requests) { item in Text(item) }`, `item` is your `struct Friends_Requests_Data`. You have to use `item.id` or `item.email` as `Text()` wants a `String` not a `struct`. I can't help with the second as I don't use Firestore.

Comment: Check out [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) for reading data from Firestore. Looks like you're trying to use `get` when perhaps you mean `getDocument`?

Comment: Thanks for your help! `getDocument` worked. Also `item.xyz` worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I did it!

Thanks to the help of the users above I managed to get the whole thing working.

I changed my View model function to look like this
**(Friends_Model.swift)**:

```
func getFriendRequestData() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
      
        let email = user?.email ?? "error: email"
        
        let queryRef = db.collection("users").whereField("friendRequests", arrayContains: email)
        
        queryRef.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            
            //check for errors
            if error == nil {
                print("no errors")
                
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    
                    //Update the list property in main thread
                    //DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //get all docs and create friend list
                        
                            self.friend_requests = snapshot.documents.map { d in
                                    //Create friend item for each document
                                return Friends_Requests_Data(id: d.documentID,
                                                        friendRequests: d["email"] as? String ?? "")
                                
                            }
                    //}
                }
                
            } else {
                // handle error
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
```

I also changed this in my view **(Friends_Requests.swift)**:

- Added init to call the function

```
init() {
        friends_model.getFriendRequestData()
}
```

- Changed
  (Old)

```
    List (friends_model.friend_requests) { item in
                        Text(item)
    }
```

(New)

```
    List (friends_model.friend_requests) { item in
                        Text(item.friendRequests)
    }
```